# Drawing a rectangle on some area in window causing screen flickering

Tags: c, windows, winapi

In my paint function, I have clear screen by drawing black rectangle over screen and then draw set of horizontal and vertical lines for displaying some graph. In my application, x-axis is very long. So i used scroll along horizontal for allowing user to view data on x-axis. Below are part of program that draw background and lines as describe above.

```
case WM_PAINT:
HRGN hrgnUpdate = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
if (GetUpdateRgn(m_hWnd, hrgnUpdate, FALSE) != NULLREGION)
{
    if (BeginPaint(m_hWnd, &ps))
    {
        HBRUSH hBr;
        hBr = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
        RECT rect;
        // Set rect to window size 
        // Draw black background. This will also work like erasing previous data.
        FillRect( m_hDC, &rect, hBr ) ;

        COLORREF testColor = RGB(0,255,0);
        HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 0, testColor);
        HPEN hOldPen = (HPEN) SelectObject(m_hDC, hPen);

        // Draw Numbers of Horizontal and Vertical lines using MoveToEx and LineTo.

    }

    EndPaint(m_hWnd, &ps);
}
break;
```

It appear that every time I scroll window by dragging scroll bar, screen is flickered. It seems to me that when background is drawn, it shows on window immediately before lines are drawn, and then lines are drawn and shown on screen.

Is there anyway to ensure that all drawing update on screen only after all lines are drawn? Or is there any way to delay the effect of background drawing until all lines are drawn?

Comment: Yes, double buffering (check  WS_EX_COMPOSITED window style). Moreover you're creating brush for each painting (and this is somehow a pretty expansive task both in terms of resources and time). There is not in your code but do you release resources too?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about creating brush. I will do some thing about it :)

Comment: Draw the background in `WM_ERASEBKGRND`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Appreciate your comment :) But in future, I am also planning on drawing a black rectangle to hide some part of graph. In that case, i will eventually need to do it inside WM_PAINT.

Comment: I cannot read your mind. The code in the question is poorly done. The `FillRect` needs to be in `WM_ERASEBKGRND`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes using double buffering: add `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` window style to your window (among other things, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). It can be done *by hand* too painting everything inside a bitmap created with `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` and then copying its content to screen DC using `BitBlt()`.

Moreover you're creating a new brush for each paint event, this is somehow a pretty expansive task both in terms of resources and time. Create it just once, for example inside `WM_CREATE` handler, and reuse it in every `WM_PAINT` (of course it is not mandatory and nowadays probably you won't ever see any difference; if you don't then don't forget to call `DeleteObject()` to release them):

```
case WM_CREATE:
    // Add your existing code for this event
    hBackgroundBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
    hForegroundPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 0, RGB(0, 255, 0));
    break;
```

Your code isn't complete so I can't say but you should also release allocated resources (and restore drawing objects).

As pointed out by David in a comment you shouldn't also mix foreground and background painting. The way it's done now it'll paint first background (by window itself) and then erased by your `WM_PAINT` message (with `FillRect()`). You have two ways to improve that: handle background painting in the proper place (then, as suggested in the comment, inside `WM_ERASEBKGRND` event handler) or avoiding Windows to paint control background and do everything inside your `WM_PAINT` event handler. Let's see both:

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
{
    GetClientRect(m_hWnd, &rect);
    FillRect((HDC)wParam), &rect, hBackgroundBrush);

    return (LRESULT)1;
}
case WM_PAINT:
{
    HRGN hrgnUpdate = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    if (GetUpdateRgn(m_hWnd, hrgnUpdate, FALSE) != NULLREGION) {
        if (BeginPaint(m_hWnd, &ps)) {
            HPEN hOldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(m_hDC, hForegroundPen);
            // Do painting here
            SelectObject(m_hDC, hOldPen);

            EndPaint(m_hWnd, &ps);
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Second case is somehow simpler, just do nothing for `WM_ERASEBKGND` (but inform Windows you handled that) and keep `WM_PAINT` as is:

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND:
    return (LRESULT)1;
case WM_PAINT:
{
    HRGN hrgnUpdate = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    if (GetUpdateRgn(m_hWnd, hrgnUpdate, FALSE) != NULLREGION) {
        if (BeginPaint(m_hWnd, &ps)) {
            FillRect(m_hDC, &rect, hBackgroundBrush);

            HPEN hOldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(m_hDC, hForegroundPen);
            // Do painting here
            SelectObject(m_hDC, hOldPen);

            EndPaint(m_hWnd, &ps);
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: In your `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler, shouldn't you use device context provided by `WPARAM` instead of calling `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` ?

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff pretty right, I just copied & pasted from one handle to the other!

Comment: I was scared for a moment that my understanding of handling `WM_ERASEBKGND` was wrong. Thank you for replying so fast and clarifying my doubts. Upvoted. Best regards.

Comment: The GetUpdateRgn call is an unnecessary optimization attempt.  If it ever is NULLREGION (which I doubt), you'll never call BeginPaint and EndPaint, and thus you'll end up in an infinite paint loop.  Start with the BeginPaint, and then check to see if the PAINTSTRUCT's rcPaint rectangle overlaps anything interesting in the drawing.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I half agree. It may be done in a different/better way (I tried to keep code as much possible as original one) but region can be NULLREGION when scrolling is involved (especially when combined with clipping).

Comment: @Adriano:  Even in that case, it's better to check rcPaint.  In no case do you want to skip the BeginPaint/EndPaint (or whatever validation scheme you're using).

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I'd always use `GetUpdateRgn()` (primary because `rcPaint` will be aggregation of invalidated regions and for small far regions you may end up to redraw all area). Window will continue to receive `WM_PAINT` only **if region is not empty**. In this case (`NULLREGION`) region is empty then it won't receive any other `WM_PAINT` message even if `BeginPaint()` is omitted.